# Blank image when saving an imshow matplotlib figure in iPython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I'm using iPython notebook w/ matplotlib to display a bunch of images inline, but now it's come time to save a number of these images (think for-loop, i.e. not a small number of images to save). My issue seems to be something to do with how I'm using iPython since I could do this alright when my script was a standalone.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
....
grid_z2 = griddata(....)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([1,1,1,1])
plt.imshow(grid_z2.transpose(),origin='Lower')
plt.colorbar()
plt.draw()
fig.savefig('slicemap.png')
```

I have also tried plt.savefig(), fig1 = plt.gcf() before plt.imshow then trying to save fig1... always every single time a blank file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the plots displayed correctly in ipython? calling `fig.savefig()` seems to work fine inside notebook cells here.

Comment: Are those commands all in the same cell?  inline (iirc) destroys the backing objects after it is done drawing.

Comment: I think I figured out my problem - I was doing multiple plots but I wasn't making a new figure. Somehow ipython was displaying correctly, but of course it wasn't saving.